# Migrate System.Web Caching to Azure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, caching, azure-web-app-service

I have some legacy Web Forms applications that were recently migrated from IIS to Azure App Service. The areas of the application using **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache** appear to no longer be working. There are areas of functionality that still work perfectly in IIS that are no longer caching data in Azure.

What is the proper way to either get this working or replace the Caching used?

```
If Not HttpContext.Current.Cache("cacheTemptTable") Is Nothing Then
     dt = CType(HttpContext.Current.Cache("cacheTemptTable"), DataTable)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Cache can provide a per instance cache. It will work with no issue with a web app plan which has 1 instance. If your web app plan has more than 1 instance, It will get inconsistent data between instances.

For your issue, you could store the cache data in a shared/distribute place. For example Azure Redis Cache. For how to use Azure Redis Cache, link below is for your reference.

[How to Use Azure Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache)